# Why my LINQ Where clause concatenating a string and call 'contains' using a value is not working?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, contains, concatenation

I am trying to filter data from db using two columns.

The thing is that the user only posts a single field, and I will use that field to check if there is any record on database that concatenating both columns values exist.

At the moment I have the following:

```
query
  .Where(x => string
     .Concat(x.Field1, " ", x.Field2)
     .Contains(parameter.MyValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

My problem is that the data is not being filtered this is weird, does anyone knows what is happening? thank you!

Comment: Are you just calling `query.Where(...)`?  `Where`  _returns_ a new query so you'd need something like `query = query.Where(...)` or `var filteredQuery = query.Where(...)` if you want to keep the original query intact.

Comment: put a breakpoint in the lamba and watch for matches

Comment: @MatthewWhited It's an expression that will be parsed by the query provider, not a method that's being executed.

Comment: Then do a .tostring and take the query to you database tools.

Comment: @D Stanley has the answer, please D Stanley make a "proper" answer so I accept it! I am so dumb, this was a typo from my side, shame on me (I don't even deserve to be here in this wonderful community lol)

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention which your db provider is. But you could try this:

```
query
  .Where(x => 
      ((x.Field1 ?? "") + " " + (x.Field2 ?? "")).Contains(parameter.MyValue));
```

This code assumes your `parameter` and its `MyValue` property are both not null, and the latter is also not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because your LINQ provider knows nothing about the Concat method. Try the same with the + operator.

Comment: If the problem was that the query provider didn't support it, it would throw an error saying as much, it wouldn't just ignore the filter.

Comment: What query provider is going to just ignore the invalid method used and not filter the data?  Different providers might fail *differently*, but they wouldn't do *nothing*.  And it's not my question.

Comment: That would depend on the query provider.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is ensure that the Sql (I assume you are querying a relational database) being generated is working when run directly against the database.

You could get the Sql statement either using a profiler, during a debug session in Visual Studio you may be able to get it via a trace, or my preference is to use LinqPad. Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412902/4490) methods also.

Your query looks correct, I was able to get it to return results from my database.

Alternative queries:

```
query
  .Where(x => x.Field1.Contains(parameter.MyValue) || x.Field2.Contains(parameter.MyValue));


query.Select(x => new 
                  { 
                    Field = string.Concat(x.Field1, " ", x.Field2), 
                    RowData = x 
                  })
     .Where(x => x.Field.Contains(parameter.MyValue));
```